# Acesso direto Action Formulario

Tags: php, formulário

Fala galera, recentemente comecei a estudar php e estou enfrentando alguns problemas, o mais recente foi o seguinte.

Tenho um formulário de login/registro e temos o seguinte código.

```
<form action="/includes/login/class_registro.php" method="post">
            <div class="input-container">
                <input type="text" id="reg_username" required="required" name="username" autocomplete="off" />
                <label for="reg_username">Usuario</label>
                <div class="bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-container">
                <input type="email" id="reg_email" required="required" name="email" autocomplete="off"/>
                <label for="reg_email">Email</label>
                <div class="bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-container">
                <input type="password" id="reg_pwd" required="required" name="password" autocomplete="off"/>
                <label for="reg_pwd">Senha</label>
                <div class="bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-container">
                <input type="password" id="reg_confirm_pwd" required="required" autocomplete="off"/>
                <label for="reg_confirm_pwd">Repita a senha</label>
                <div class="bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="button-container">
                <button name="btn_rg" value="enviar"><span>Concluir</span></button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

O problema é que se o usuario fizer www.meusite.com.br/includes/login/class_registro.php ele consegue acessar o arquivo normalmente, então fiz o seguinte:

```
//Verifica se o acesso foi realizado diretamente pela URL
$enviou = (isset($_POST["btn_rg"]) && !empty($_POST["btn_rg"])) ? true :          false;
if (!$enviou) {
header("Location: http://www.meusite.com.br/login");
}
//Verifica se o acesso foi realizado diretamente pela URL
```

Mas fiquei na dúvida se não teria alguma forma "melhor" de se fazer esse procedimento, o mesmo acontece para www.meusite.com.br/includes/login/class_login.php

Comment: mais simplificada, dispensa o if ...  e põe somente     $enviou = ((isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_POST["submit"]))) ? header("Location: http://www.meusite.com.br/login") :  false;

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de usar

```
<button name="btn_rg" value="enviar"><span>Concluir</span></button>
```

tente usar

```
<input type="submit" value ="Enviar">
```

Serviu?

Comment: Mas o formulário está sendo enviado normalmente Herbert, o meu problema é tornar a url a que o formulário está sendo enviado que é /includes/login/class_registro.php não ser acessa diretamente.

Comment: Você chegou a testar? O type button não foi feito para ser utilizado para dar um submit no formulário ... acho que no momento que você utilizar o submit no formulário ele vai atribuir o método somente ao clique do botão ...

Answer (score 0):

Senhores, estou tendo um problema parecido. Só que o meu action não funciona. Ele funcionou há uns meses, mas não guardei a solucão e quando voltei a mexer no projeto, aí está o erro novamente.

```
<div class="container">
```

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="frmcontatoazul" action="loja/controller/envio.php" method="get">
  <fieldset>

    <!-- Form Name -->
    <legend>Contato</legend>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="txtinputnome">Nome</label>  
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <input id="txtinputnome" name="txtinputnome" placeholder="Escreva seu nome completo" class="form-control input-md" required="required" type="text" />
        <span class="help-block">help</span>  
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="txtinputemail">Email</label>  
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <input id="txtinputemail" name="txtinputemail" placeholder="Coloque um email válido" class="form-control input-md" required="required" type="email" />
        <span class="help-block">help</span>  
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Textarea -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="txtinputarea">Mensagem</label>
      <div class="col-md-8">                     
        <textarea class="form-control" id="txtinputarea" rows="6" name="txtinputarea" placeholder="Digite sua Pergunta"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="btnenviar"></label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <button id="btnenviar" name="btnenviar" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Enviar</button>
        <?php
          var_dump($_GET);
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>


  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Agora vou mandar a estrutura dos meus arquivos. E uma foto da página que estou criando. Estou usando o smarty php engine. já tentei "envio", o caminho completo como tá aí, envio.php, o caminho com envio.php no final, só com envio e nada funciona.